# pull images from table based on categories and stop duplicated results

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

tables
[image]
sample data

walls

```
wall_id   wall_name
  1        wall_1
  2        wall_2
  6        wall_6
```

wall_categories

```
wall_id   category_id
  1           2
  2           1
  6           1
  6           2
```

categories

```
category_id  category_name
  1            Wallpaper
  2            Photography
```

html

```
<a href="file.php?sort=upload_date">Date</a>
<a href="file.php?sort=wall_views">Views</a>
<a href="file.php?sort=wall_downloads">Downloads</a>

<a href="file.php?filter=1">Wallpaper</a>
<a href="file.php?filter=2">Photography</a>
```

php

```
$sortBy = array('upload_date','wall_views','wall_downloads');
$sort = 'upload_date';
if(isset($_GET['sort']) && inarray($_GET['sort'], $sortBy)){
   $sort = $_GET['sort'];
}


$filterBy = array(1, 2);
$filter = join(',', $filterBy);
if(isset($_GET['sort']) && inarray($_GET['sort'], $sortBy)){
   $sort = $_GET['sort'];
}
```

I'm trying to pull 
`wall_id`, `wall_name`, `wall_views` from `walls` table and `category_name` from categories table based on `wall_categories` table. Below is the query I got:

```
$walls_query = $connectDB->prepare("SELECT * FROM walls INNER JOIN wall_categories ON
                walls.wall_id = wall_categories.wall_id WHERE wall_categories.category_id  
                IN ($filter) AND walls.wall_id>? ORDER BY $sort DESC;");
     $query->execute();
```

and here is the query that selects the categories from database using the wall_id

```
$categories_query = $connectDB->prepare("SELECT category_name FROM categories INNER JOIN wall_categories 
    ON wall_categories.category_id = categories.category_id WHERE wall_id=?;");
```

The problem is it generates duplicate data, the images that have two categories are displayed twice. Need to stop that.

Comment: I don't understand why there are two queries :-( Just gather all the data and handle the rest in php or javascript

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You've outlined your design and said what you want to achieve. I think what you're asking can be done by: GET-ing the parameters through the PHP, then determine your query from those.

Comment: I guess the first query doesn't make any sense. Let me remove it. haha!

Comment: DISTINCT * doesn't make any sense either

Comment: sorry forgot to remove that, I was actually trying if that would work. thanks for correcting!